# Unable to expand filesystem on SD card running Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, partition

I'm new to Raspberry Pi and I just flashed the SD card and installed Raspbian on it. After reboot, I used `raspi -config` to expand file system. However, I get the error

> Your partition layout is not currently supported by this tool. You are
>   probably using NOOBS.

I am not using NOOBS since I just installed Raspbian. Then why am I getting this error?

Additional details-

`uname -a` shows:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ #474 PREEMPT Thu Jun 13 17:14:42 BST 2013 armv61 GNU/Linux
```

`df -h` shows:

```
Filesystem        Size        Used       Avail    Use%    Mounted On
rootfs            6.0G        1.6G       4.3G     29%     /
/dev/root         6.0G        1.5G       5.4G     29%     /
devtmpfs          235M        0          235M     0%      /dev
tmpfs             49M         256K       49M      1%      /run
tmpfs             5.0M        0          5.0M     0%      /run/lock 
tmpfs             98M         0          98M      0%      /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p5    56M         19M        38M      33%     /boot
```

Comment: It may be more helpful if you post the full output of df -h.

Comment: did you reboot after resizing? It only resizes when it reboots. How big is your SD card?

Comment: @joan I updated df-h. I was unable to resize, as I've mentioned in the question. Size of Card is 8 GB.
(Even if you conclude it already is resized, the question is why does it not let me do the process again. Why does it feel I'm probably running NOOBS?)

Comment: Given that / (root) is shown as 6GB the partition has been resized.  It won't let you do it again as there is nothing else to do.

Comment: Are you using `raspi -config` or `raspi-config`. I hope it is a formatting mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Select ***Advanced Options*** shown in fig

[image: Advanced Options]

Next Select the ***Expand File System*** as shown in fig

[image: Expand File System]

Then hit *Enter* followed by hit *Finish*

Now Reboot your machine.

Kudos!!!, Your File system is expanded.